# Flutter UI - How can I add more IconButtons to the trailing CupertinoSliverNavigationBar?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

Tried to research around but couldn't find a solution. I would like to use the CupertinoSliverNavigationBar which is the large title version of the top navigation bar I could achieve this in Xcode Storyboard but simply adding buttons to the top bar but the `trailing` option only allows a single widget.

I tried using a `Row()` but that messes up the location and the title aloooot.

Comment: Did you specify `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to `Row` ?

Comment: Just incase, do you know how to remove the shadow on the bottom?

Comment: of icons or of navigation bar? anyhow search the elevation property, must be somewhere in the code of the widget

Comment: The navigation bar itself. I did it with the regular app bar but I can’t find it with the sliver version

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Composing your comment coversation into an answer:

```
 CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
   trailing: Row(
     mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
     children: ...
   ))
```

You also asked how one would go about removing the *shadow below* the navigation bar. That is **impossible** *with the `CupertinoSliverNavitionBar` `Widget`*. Taking a [look at the constructor](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSliverNavigationBar/CupertinoSliverNavigationBar.html), you will notice that there is nothing like an `elevation` value. You would have to create a custom widget for this.

This also makes sense because it should look like "[iOS-11-style](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSliverNavigationBar-class.html)" and removing the shadow would remove that feature.

Comment: I’m able to remove the shadow from the storyboard/in code in Xcode I just thought it would be the same in flutter. Thanks though!